# Long query cause System.StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql

I have a very long query in Linq to Sql to populate DataGrid as follows:

```
var query = from c in dc.Hotel_Meals_TBLs 
select new
{
    Code = c.HotelCodePrimary,
    CountryCode = c.CountryCode,
    CityCode = c.CityCode,
    HotelCode = c.HotelCode,
    Stars = c.StarCode,
    WWW = c.WWWCode,
    ABF = c.ABFCode,
    Location = c.LocationCode,
    Currency = c.CurrencyCode,
    CodeCode = c.HotelCode,
    No = c.NoCode,
    HotelName = c.HotelName,
    HFROM = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("High")).FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID)._From,
    HTO = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("High")).FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID)._To,
    HFROM2 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("High")).Skip(1).Take(1).First()._From,
    HTO2 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("High")).Skip(1).Take(1).First()._To,
    HFROM3 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("High")).Skip(2).Take(1).First()._From,
    HTO3 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("High")).Skip(2).Take(1).First()._To,
    HFROM4 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("High")).Skip(3).Take(1).First()._From,
    HTO4 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("High")).Skip(3).Take(1).First()._To,
    HFROM5 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("High")).Skip(4).Take(1).First()._From,
    HTO5 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("High")).Skip(4).Take(1).First()._To,
    HFROM6 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("High")).Skip(5).Take(1).First()._From,
    HTO6 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("High")).Skip(5).Take(1).First()._To,
    HFROM7 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("High")).Skip(6).Take(1).First()._From,
    HTO7 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("High")).Skip(6).Take(1).First()._To,
    HFROM8 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("High")).Skip(7).Take(1).First()._From,
    HTO8 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("High")).Skip(7).Take(1).First()._To,
    HFROM9 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("High")).Skip(8).Take(1).First()._From,
    HTO9 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("High")).Skip(8).Take(1).First()._To,
    HFROM10 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("High")).Skip(9).Take(1).First()._From,
    HTO10 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("High")).Skip(9).Take(1).First()._To,
    PFROM = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Peak")).FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID)._From,
    PTO = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Peak")).FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID)._To,
    PFROM2 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Peak")).Skip(1).Take(1).First()._From,
    PTO2 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Peak")).Skip(1).Take(1).First()._To,
    PFROM3 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Peak")).Skip(2).Take(1).First()._From,
    PTO3 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Peak")).Skip(2).Take(1).First()._To,
    PFROM4 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Peak")).Skip(3).Take(1).First()._From,
    PTO4 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Peak")).Skip(3).Take(1).First()._To,
    PFROM5 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Peak")).Skip(4).Take(1).First()._From,
    PTO5 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Peak")).Skip(4).Take(1).First()._To,
    PFROM6 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Peak")).Skip(5).Take(1).First()._From,
    PTO6 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Peak")).Skip(5).Take(1).First()._To,
    PFROM7 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Peak")).Skip(6).Take(1).First()._From,
    PTO7 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Peak")).Skip(6).Take(1).First()._To,
    PFROM8 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Peak")).Skip(7).Take(1).First()._From,
    PTO8 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Peak")).Skip(7).Take(1).First()._To,
    PFROM9 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Peak")).Skip(8).Take(1).First()._From,
    PTO9 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Peak")).Skip(8).Take(1).First()._To,
    PFROM10 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Peak")).Skip(9).Take(1).First()._From,
    PTO10 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Peak")).Skip(9).Take(1).First()._To,
    TPFROM = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("ExtraPeak")).FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID)._From,
    TPTO = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("ExtraPeak")).FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID)._To,
    TPFROM2 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("ExtraPeak")).Skip(1).Take(1).First()._From,
    TPTO2 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("ExtraPeak")).Skip(1).Take(1).First()._To,
    TPFROM3 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("ExtraPeak")).Skip(2).Take(1).First()._From,
    TPTO3 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("ExtraPeak")).Skip(2).Take(1).First()._To,
    SFROM = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Shoulder")).FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID)._From,
    STO = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Shoulder")).FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID)._To,
    SFROM2 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Shoulder")).Skip(1).Take(1).First()._From,
    STO2 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Shoulder")).Skip(1).Take(1).First()._To,
    SFROM3 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Shoulder")).Skip(2).Take(1).First()._From,
    STO3 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Shoulder")).Skip(2).Take(1).First()._To,
    LFROM = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Low")).FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID)._From,
    LTO = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Low")).FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID)._To,
    LFROM2 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Low")).Skip(1).Take(1).First()._From,
    LTO2 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Low")).Skip(1).Take(1).First()._To,
    LFROM3 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Low")).Skip(2).Take(1).First()._From,
    LTO3 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Low")).Skip(2).Take(1).First()._To,
    LFROM4 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Low")).Skip(3).Take(1).First()._From,
    LTO4 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Low")).Skip(3).Take(1).First()._To,
    LFROM5 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Low")).Skip(4).Take(1).First()._From,
    LTO5 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Low")).Skip(4).Take(1).First()._To,
    LFROM6 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Low")).Skip(5).Take(1).First()._From,
    LTO6 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Low")).Skip(5).Take(1).First()._To,
    LFROM7 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Low")).Skip(6).Take(1).First()._From,
    LTO7 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Low")).Skip(6).Take(1).First()._To,
    LFROM8 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Low")).Skip(7).Take(1).First()._From,
    LTO8 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Low")).Skip(7).Take(1).First()._To,
    LFROM9 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Low")).Skip(8).Take(1).First()._From,
    LTO9 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Low")).Skip(8).Take(1).First()._To,
    LFROM10 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Low")).Skip(9).Take(1).First()._From,
    LTO10 = c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("Low")).Skip(9).Take(1).First()._To,
    BF = c.Breakfast,
    LUN = c.Lunch,
    DIN = c.Dinner,
    _24Dec = c._24Dec,
    _31Dec = c._31Dec,
    ROOM1 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).RoomName,
    SGLH1 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).SGL_HighSeason,
    DBLH1 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).DBL_HighSeason,
    TPLH1 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).TPL_HighSeason,
    SGLP1 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).SGL_PeakSeason,
    DBLP1 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).DBL_PeakSeason,
    TPLP1 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).TPL_PeakSeason,
    SGLTP1 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).SGL_TopPeakSeason,
    DBLTP1 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).DBL_TopPeakSeason,
    TPLTP1 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).TPL_TopPeakSeason,
    SGLS1 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).SGL_ShoulderSeason,
    DBLS1 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).DBL_ShoulderSeason,
    TPLS1 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).TPL_ShoulderSeason,
    SGLL1 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).SGL_LowSeason,
    DBLL1 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).DBL_LowSeason,
    TPLL1 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).TPL_LowSeason,
    ROOM2 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(1).Take(1).First().RoomName,
    SGLH2 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(1).Take(1).First().SGL_HighSeason,
    DBLH2 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(1).Take(1).First().DBL_HighSeason,
    TPLH2 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(1).Take(1).First().TPL_HighSeason,
    SGLP2 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(1).Take(1).First().SGL_PeakSeason,
    DBLP2 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(1).Take(1).First().DBL_PeakSeason,
    TPLP2 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(1).Take(1).First().TPL_PeakSeason,
    SGLTP2 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(1).Take(1).First().SGL_TopPeakSeason,
    DBLTP2 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(1).Take(1).First().DBL_TopPeakSeason,
    TPLTP2 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(1).Take(1).First().TPL_TopPeakSeason,
    SGLS2 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(1).Take(1).First().SGL_ShoulderSeason,
    DBLS2 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(1).Take(1).First().DBL_ShoulderSeason,
    TPLS2 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(1).Take(1).First().TPL_ShoulderSeason,
    SGLL2 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(1).Take(1).First().SGL_LowSeason,
    DBLL2 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(1).Take(1).First().DBL_LowSeason,
    TPLL2 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(1).Take(1).First().TPL_LowSeason,
    ROOM3 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(2).Take(1).First().RoomName,
    SGLH3 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(2).Take(1).First().SGL_HighSeason,
    DBLH3 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(2).Take(1).First().DBL_HighSeason,
    TPLH3 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(2).Take(1).First().TPL_HighSeason,
    SGLP3 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(2).Take(1).First().SGL_PeakSeason,
    DBLP3 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(2).Take(1).First().DBL_PeakSeason,
    TPLP3 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(2).Take(1).First().TPL_PeakSeason,
    SGLTP3 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(2).Take(1).First().SGL_TopPeakSeason,
    DBLTP3 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(2).Take(1).First().DBL_TopPeakSeason,
    TPLTP3 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(2).Take(1).First().TPL_TopPeakSeason,
    SGLS3 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(2).Take(1).First().SGL_ShoulderSeason,
    DBLS3 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(2).Take(1).First().DBL_ShoulderSeason,
    TPLS3 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(2).Take(1).First().TPL_ShoulderSeason,
    SGLL3 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(2).Take(1).First().SGL_LowSeason,
    DBLL3 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(2).Take(1).First().DBL_LowSeason,
    TPLL3 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(2).Take(1).First().TPL_LowSeason,
    ROOM4 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(3).Take(1).First().RoomName,
    SGLH4 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(3).Take(1).First().SGL_HighSeason,
    DBLH4 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(3).Take(1).First().DBL_HighSeason,
    TPLH4 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(3).Take(1).First().TPL_HighSeason,
    SGLP4 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(3).Take(1).First().SGL_PeakSeason,
    DBLP4 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(3).Take(1).First().DBL_PeakSeason,
    TPLP4 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(3).Take(1).First().TPL_PeakSeason,
    SGLTP4 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(3).Take(1).First().SGL_TopPeakSeason,
    DBLTP4 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(3).Take(1).First().DBL_TopPeakSeason,
    TPLTP4 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(3).Take(1).First().TPL_TopPeakSeason,
    SGLS4 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(3).Take(1).First().SGL_ShoulderSeason,
    DBLS4 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(3).Take(1).First().DBL_ShoulderSeason,
    TPLS4 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(3).Take(1).First().TPL_ShoulderSeason,
    SGLL4 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(3).Take(1).First().SGL_LowSeason,
    DBLL4 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(3).Take(1).First().DBL_LowSeason,
    TPLL4 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(3).Take(1).First().TPL_LowSeason,
    ROOM5 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(4).Take(1).First().RoomName,
    SGLH5 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(4).Take(1).First().SGL_HighSeason,
    DBLH5 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(4).Take(1).First().DBL_HighSeason,
    TPLH5 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(4).Take(1).First().TPL_HighSeason,
    SGLP5 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(4).Take(1).First().SGL_PeakSeason,
    DBLP5 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(4).Take(1).First().DBL_PeakSeason,
    TPLP5 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(4).Take(1).First().TPL_PeakSeason,
    SGLTP5 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(4).Take(1).First().SGL_TopPeakSeason,
    DBLTP5 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(4).Take(1).First().DBL_TopPeakSeason,
    TPLTP5 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(4).Take(1).First().TPL_TopPeakSeason,
    SGLS5 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(4).Take(1).First().SGL_ShoulderSeason,
    DBLS5 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(4).Take(1).First().DBL_ShoulderSeason,
    TPLS5 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(4).Take(1).First().TPL_ShoulderSeason,
    SGLL5 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(4).Take(1).First().SGL_LowSeason,
    DBLL5 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(4).Take(1).First().DBL_LowSeason,
    TPLL5 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(4).Take(1).First().TPL_LowSeason,
    ROOM6 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(5).Take(1).First().RoomName,
    SGLH6 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(5).Take(1).First().SGL_HighSeason,
    DBLH6 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(5).Take(1).First().DBL_HighSeason,
    TPLH6 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(5).Take(1).First().TPL_HighSeason,
    SGLP6 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(5).Take(1).First().SGL_PeakSeason,
    DBLP6 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(5).Take(1).First().DBL_PeakSeason,
    TPLP6 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(5).Take(1).First().TPL_PeakSeason,
    SGLTP6 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(5).Take(1).First().SGL_TopPeakSeason,
    DBLTP6 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(5).Take(1).First().DBL_TopPeakSeason,
    TPLTP6 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(5).Take(1).First().TPL_TopPeakSeason,
    SGLS6 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(5).Take(1).First().SGL_ShoulderSeason,
    DBLS6 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(5).Take(1).First().DBL_ShoulderSeason,
    TPLS6 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(5).Take(1).First().TPL_ShoulderSeason,
    SGLL6 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(5).Take(1).First().SGL_LowSeason,
    DBLL6 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(5).Take(1).First().DBL_LowSeason,
    TPLL6 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(5).Take(1).First().TPL_LowSeason,
    ROOM7 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(6).Take(1).First().RoomName,
    SGLH7 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(6).Take(1).First().SGL_HighSeason,
    DBLH7 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(6).Take(1).First().DBL_HighSeason,
    TPLH7 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(6).Take(1).First().TPL_HighSeason,
    SGLP7 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(6).Take(1).First().SGL_PeakSeason,
    DBLP7 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(6).Take(1).First().DBL_PeakSeason,
    TPLP7 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(6).Take(1).First().TPL_PeakSeason,
    SGLTP7 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(6).Take(1).First().SGL_TopPeakSeason,
    DBLTP7 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(6).Take(1).First().DBL_TopPeakSeason,
    TPLTP7 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(6).Take(1).First().TPL_TopPeakSeason,
    SGLS7 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(6).Take(1).First().SGL_ShoulderSeason,
    DBLS7 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(6).Take(1).First().DBL_ShoulderSeason,
    TPLS7 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(6).Take(1).First().TPL_ShoulderSeason,
    SGLL7 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(6).Take(1).First().SGL_LowSeason,
    DBLL7 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(6).Take(1).First().DBL_LowSeason,
    TPLL7 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(6).Take(1).First().TPL_LowSeason,
    ROOM8 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(7).Take(1).First().RoomName,
    SGLH8 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(7).Take(1).First().SGL_HighSeason,
    DBLH8 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(7).Take(1).First().DBL_HighSeason,
    TPLH8 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(7).Take(1).First().TPL_HighSeason,
    SGLP8 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(7).Take(1).First().SGL_PeakSeason,
    DBLP8 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(7).Take(1).First().DBL_PeakSeason,
    TPLP8 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(7).Take(1).First().TPL_PeakSeason,
    SGLTP8 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(7).Take(1).First().SGL_TopPeakSeason,
    DBLTP8 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(7).Take(1).First().DBL_TopPeakSeason,
    TPLTP8 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(7).Take(1).First().TPL_TopPeakSeason,
    SGLS8 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(7).Take(1).First().SGL_ShoulderSeason,
    DBLS8 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(7).Take(1).First().DBL_ShoulderSeason,
    TPLS8 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(7).Take(1).First().TPL_ShoulderSeason,
    SGLL8 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(7).Take(1).First().SGL_LowSeason,
    DBLL8 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(7).Take(1).First().DBL_LowSeason,
    TPLL8 = c.HotelRoom_TBLs.Skip(7).Take(1).First().TPL_LowSeason,
    CivicNumber =c.Number,
    Street =c.Street,
    District =c.District,
    City =c.City,
    Country =c.Country,
    Tel =c.Tel,
    Fax =c.Fax,
    TotalRoom =c.TotalRoom,
    RoomFacilities =c.RoomFacilities,
    RestaurantBar =c.Restaurant_Bar,
    HotelFacilities =c.HotelFacilities,
    GM = c.HotelContact_TBLs.Where(d => d.ContactType.Contains("GM")).SingleOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).Name,
    GMMobile = c.HotelContact_TBLs.Where(d => d.ContactType.Contains("GM")).SingleOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).Mobile,
    GMDirectTel = c.HotelContact_TBLs.Where(d => d.ContactType.Contains("GM")).SingleOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).DirectTel,
    GMDirectFax = c.HotelContact_TBLs.Where(d => d.ContactType.Contains("GM")).SingleOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).DirectFax,
    GMEmail = c.HotelContact_TBLs.Where(d => d.ContactType.Contains("GM")).SingleOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).Email,
    DirectorFB = c.HotelContact_TBLs.Where(d => d.ContactType.StartsWith("Dir")).SingleOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).Name,
    DirMobile = c.HotelContact_TBLs.Where(d => d.ContactType.StartsWith("Dir")).SingleOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).Mobile,
    DirEmail = c.HotelContact_TBLs.Where(d => d.ContactType.StartsWith("Dir")).SingleOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).Email,
    DOS = c.HotelContact_TBLs.Where(d => d.ContactType.StartsWith("DOS")).SingleOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).Name,
    DOSMobile =  c.HotelContact_TBLs.Where(d => d.ContactType.StartsWith("DOS")).SingleOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).Mobile,
    DOSEmail =  c.HotelContact_TBLs.Where(d => d.ContactType.StartsWith("DOS")).SingleOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).Email,
    DOSSkype =  c.HotelContact_TBLs.Where(d => d.ContactType.StartsWith("DOS")).SingleOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).Skype,
    SM =  c.HotelContact_TBLs.Where(d => d.ContactType.StartsWith("SM")).SingleOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).Name,
    SMMobile = c.HotelContact_TBLs.Where(d => d.ContactType.StartsWith("SM")).SingleOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).Mobile,
    SMEmail = c.HotelContact_TBLs.Where(d => d.ContactType.StartsWith("SM")).SingleOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).Email,
    SMSkype =c.HotelContact_TBLs.Where(d => d.ContactType.StartsWith("SM")).SingleOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).Skype,
    RSVN = c.HotelContact_TBLs.Where(d => d.ContactType.StartsWith("RSVN")).SingleOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).Name,
    RSVNMobile =c.HotelContact_TBLs.Where(d => d.ContactType.StartsWith("RSVN")).SingleOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).Mobile,
    RSVNEmail =c.HotelContact_TBLs.Where(d => d.ContactType.StartsWith("RSVN")).SingleOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).Email,
    RSVNSkype =c.HotelContact_TBLs.Where(d => d.ContactType.StartsWith("RSVN")).SingleOrDefault(a => a.HotelCodeID == c.HotelCodeID).Skype,
    FocPolicy = c.FocPolicy,
    ChildPolicy = c.ChildPolicy,
    HoneyMoon = c.HoneyMoon,
    CancellationPolicy = c.CancellationPolicy,
    PaymentTerm = c.PaymentTerm,
    BankReference = c.BankReference,
    Notes = c.Note
}
```

but when I compile it with Visual Studio 2010 I receive this error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly;{Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}

I compiled this query also with LinqPad4 and there was no errors, do you have any idea what does this message mean?

Comment: From what kind of application are you running this query? WindowsForms app or ASP.NET page? can you show us how you execute the query from your code?

Comment: @JayJay - Do you really need to show so many columns in grid?

Comment: @Davide, Hi Sir , i am developing a WPF Apps, the query will finish  as follows:  this.xamHotel.DataContext = query.ToList(); to populate an DataGrid ; anyway if you need more explanation i will share with you ,Thanks

Comment: @Giorgi, Hi Sir, i need to show 255 column in a DataGrid and after convert the data to Excel so the customer request that, i know it is so much but it's not up to me.Thanks

Comment: Yikes that query is pure evil ;p personally I would rewrite that; I suspect the skip(n).take(1) would work better via a group-by, and probably 2 (or more) queries/data-hunks stitched back together. At that level of complexity I'd also be writing TSQL not LINQ

Comment: I don't think of any benefit to write this query in linq, it's so long that maintain it is hard any way you write it, consider using a DBA to create a view or SP.

Comment: @Marc ,yeah Sir,i wrote down also in this way :var query = from c in dc.Hotel_Meals_TBLs join p in dc.HotelPeriod_TBLs on c.HotelCodeID
   equals p.HotelCodeID join r in dc.HotelRoom_TBLs on c.HotelCodeID equals r.HotelCodeID  join f in dc.HotelPeriod_TBLs on c.HotelCodeID equals f.HotelCodeID group p by p.HotelCodeID into g select new{...} but i receive the same error.Thanks for your advices

Comment: well, i am trying a better way but not luck ,do you have any code snippet to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to rewrite your query to make it less memory allocating.
Look, in every line you wrote:

```
c.HotelPeriod_TBLs.Where(d => d.PeriodName.Contains("High"))
// equal lines of code here.
```

I think this is the main problem of your query. Try to fill your data not in one query or move this query to the SQL-layer. This monster will not live very long and will produce huge problems with memory.

Comment: thanks Sir i will control it and after let you know the result.

Comment: Why do you think memory is the problem? Where is that line of code is lots of memory allocation? That line is not even executed, it's translated to SQL.

Comment: I think problem with memory arised exactly in moment of compilation LINQ to the SQL commands.

Comment: @VMAtm, could you elaborate? I'm curious what exactly do you think is the problem.